# C Example to send commands to DDE Server

Tags: c, winapi, dde

I have two problems when I copy the code.  The code I copied is shown below.  I am using Code::Blocks on Windows XP.

Problem 1:

In the code below, I get an error which says "'MyDDECallBACK' undeclared (first use in this function."  If I replace it with a 0, or comment out that line, the code runs without error (as long as I also comment out Problem 2).  I am not sure where to declare this since the example doesn't declare it, or maybe I am unsure what this is. It also doesn't seem to like the err=true unless I capitalize true?

```
if(DMLERR_NO_ERROR != DdeInitialize(&idInst, MyDDECallBack, APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0))
  err = true;
```

Problem 2:

What is the ".." near the end of the code used for?  Also, if I comment it out (along with Problem 1), the code runs.

Thanks again for your help!

```
// The following code fragment uses Windows DDEML APIs
// to send a move command to the Nucleus DDE Server
// and receives a status string.
//
// Variables and initial values.
HCONV hConv = NULL;

DWORD idInst = 0;
HSZ hszService = NULL;
HSZ hszTopic = NULL;
HSZ hszCmd = NULL;
BOOL err = FALSE;
HDDEDATA transResult = NULL;
DWORD dwResult = 0;
char result[300];
// Need long timeout value to allow the station to move and
// respond.
const long TIMEOUT = 60000;
// Initialize the DDEML environment. Create an Instance
// that is used in many other calls to DDE.
if(DMLERR_NO_ERROR != DdeInitialize(&idInst, MyDDECallBack,
                                    APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0))
  err = true;
// Create String handles for the server name, topic and item.
if(!err)
{
  hszService = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, "EDMAIN",
                                     CP_WINANSI);
  hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, "CMI Commands",
                                   CP_WINANSI);
  hszCmd = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst,
                                 ":MOVE:REL 2 100 100 NONE",
                                 CP_WINANSI);
  err = (hszService == NULL || hszTopic == NULL || hszCmd == NULL);
}
// Connect to the Nucleus DDE Server. (Open a conversation).
// Captain Picard would say, "Open a channel Mr. Wharf".
if(!err)
{
  hConv = DdeConnect(idInst, hszService, hszTopic, NULL);
  err = hConv == NULL;
  if(err)
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to make DDE connection.\n"
               "Make sure Nucleus is running.",
               "DDE CLIENT ERROR", MB_ICONSTOP);
}
// Send the command string to the server.
if (!err)
{
  transResult = DdeClientTransaction(NULL, 0, hConv, hszCmd,
                                     CF_TEXT, XTYP_REQUEST, TIMEOUT, NULL);
  // Read the result string. TransResult will be a
  // valid data handle if the client transaction above
  // was successful, and NULL if it was not. This must be
  // checked since calls to DdeGetData with a NULL handle
  // cause GPF’s.

  if(transResult)
    DdeGetData(transResult, (LPBYTE)result, sizeof(result), 0);
  // Display the result string.
  MessageBox(NULL, result, "RESULT", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
// Close the conversation.
if (hConv != NULL)
  DdeDisconnect( hConv );
// Delete the string handles.
if ((hszService != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
  DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszService );
if ((hszTopic != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
  DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszTopic );
if ((hszCmd != NULL) & (idInst != NULL))
  DdeFreeStringHandle( idInst, hszCmd );
// Clear out the DDEML environment.
if (idInst != NULL)
  DdeUninitialize(idInst);
..
// Since we are only doing requests from Nucleus, we don’t
// expect to get callbacks to this routine. Nevertheless,
// it is necessary to create a routine with no action.
HDDEDATA CALLBACK MyDDECallBack( UINT wType,
                                 UINT wFmt, HCONV HConv, 
                                 HSZ dataHandle1, HSZ dataHandle2,
                                 HDDEDATA data, DWORD myword1, 
                                 DWORD myword2)
{
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Callback is for you to get notification back from the service.   Deleting this, and you will not get the notifications which you probably need.
2. The .. is the author of the example code way to tell you *put your own logic here* -- it has no meaning in C or C++ (however 3 dots `...` does have a meaning in function declarations)

Comment: Thank you!  But how do I declare this for the function?

Comment: You need to find the definition of `MyDDECallBack` and then declare a function with that signature.